# How to use threads correctly in tkinter GUI to plot in real time?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

How to use threads correctly in tkinter GUI to plot in real time?

Could somebody please tell me how to use threads in a tkinter GUI button?

I have an interface where i want to plot data in real time from an Arduino using threading (because I want to sample data at high sampling rates such as electrophysiological signals) and show the results in real time as well in a separate matplotlib figure. The problem is that I have used the threadings as it is intended in separate scripts and the program doesn´t plot nothing and stops responding when i press the assigned button to this task.

my code is something like this:

the main window features:

```
root=tknt.Tk()
root.title("Modular Project")
root.geometry('1024x720')
root.resizable(False,False)
```

the function intend to use when i push the tkinter button to plot in real time but causes trouble:

```
def Begin_DataCap():
    COM_DataCap_Sel=COM_Entry_DataCap.get()  #Gets the user selected COM PORT
```

SECURITY FUNCTION TO AVOID UNDESIRED INPUT PARAMETERS

```
if COM_DataCap_Sel=='-----------':
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR", message=("Please introduce a valid COM port!"))
elif T_Cap.get()<1 and Fs_Cap.get()<1:
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR", message=("Please introduce valdid time and frequency values!"))
elif T_Cap.get()<1:
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR", message=("Please introduce a valid time value!"))
elif Fs_Cap.get()<1:
    messagebox.showerror("ERROR", message=("Please introduce a valid frequency value!"))
```

FUNCTION TO PLOT IN REAL TIME WHEN THE PARAMETERS ARE CORRECT

```
else:
    IsReceive = False
    IsRun = True
    value = 0
      
    #FUNCTION TO GET THE SERIAL DATA
    def getData():
        time.sleep(1.0)
        serialConnection.reset_input_buffer()

        while (IsRun == True):
            global IsReceive
            global value
            value = int(serialConnection.readline().strip())
            IsReceive = True
```

PLOTTING FUNCTION

```
    def plotData(self, Samples, serialConnection, line):
        data.append(value)
        line.set_data(range(Samples), data)
```

INITIALIZE SERIAL PORT

```
    Baudrate = 9600
    serialConnection = serial.Serial(COM_DataCap_Sel, Baudrate)
```

TEST SAMPLING PARAMETERS

```
    Samples = 1000
    data = collections.deque([0] * Samples, maxlen=Samples)
    Sampletime = 1
```

INTENDED SEPARATED MATPLOTLIB FIGURE

```
    xmin = 0
    xmax = Samples
    ymin = 0
    ymax = 1024

    fig = mplt.figure(figsize=(13, 6))
    ax = mplt.axes(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))
    mplt.title('Real-Time Reading Data')
    ax.set_xlabel('Samples')
    ax.set_ylabel('ADC resolution units')

    line = ax.plot([], [])[0]
```

THE FIGURE UPDATER

```
    thread = Thread(target=getData,daemon=True).start()<-------The thread i used

    while (IsReceive != True):
        time.sleep(0.1)

    anim = mpan.FuncAnimation(fig, plotData, fargs=(Samples, serialConnection, line), frames=Samples,interval=Sampletime, repeat=False)
    mplt.show()
```

FINISHING FUNCTION

```
    thread.join()
    IsRun = False
    serialConnection.close()
```

The button I assigned to the function

```
Start_DataCap=tknt.Button(Data_Cap_Frame,text='Start Data Capture',command=Begin_DataCap)
Start_DataCap.grid(row=7, column=0,padx=0,pady=10)
```

What am i doing wrong and how do i fix it?

Comment: Are you able to create a [mcve] so it's easier to help you?

Comment: what do you mean run in separate script?